# How does the data structure for a lexical analysis look?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I know the lexical analyser tokenizes the input and stores it in a stream, or at least that is what I understood. Unfortunately nearly all articles I have read only talk about lexing simple expressions. What I am interested in is how to tokenize something like:

```
if (fooBar > 5) {
  for (var i = 0; i < alot.length; i++) {
    fooBar += 2 + i;
  }
}
```

*Please note that this is pseudo code.*

**Question:** I would like to know how the data structure looks like for tokens created by the lexer? I really have no idea for the example i gave above where code is nested. Some example would be nice.

Comment: Depending on your need and goals, you might not need any special data structure *at all*. All a parser needs from a lexer is basically a sequence of integers, where each integer corresponds to a specific token-type. So you have one value for the keyword `if`, one value for the opening parenthesis, etc. There are thousands of examples of lexers all over the Internet, quite a few with more information than a single token-type value. Try to find them, and see what they do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so I dont need to order the tokens? For example: array with expressions etc

Comment: Well if the parser doesn't get the tokens in the correct order, how could it parse it? How could it check for errors? Perhaps you can elaborate what you mean by "data structure"? Because as a minimum only an integer value is needed (as I previously explained).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so probably something like: var tokensArray = [["identifier", "fooBar"], ["operator", "+="]];

Comment: then the parser would loop through the tokens and checks if the order is correct and in the language

Comment: That is a common way to pass tokens, if more context is needed. And for that all you need is a simple structure with two members: The token type (usually an integer or enumeration type) and the lexeme (usually a string or a `union`).

Comment: Or are you more interested in how the lexer passes on the tokens to the parser? Is that what you mean?

Comment: you might consider taking a look at libclang, it produces an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) which is used for other analysis (like semantic analysis)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude im interested indeed. Should I post a new question? I think you are right, id love to know how the lexer passes on the tokens.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude by the way, im sorry if my question is of low quality. Let me know if there is anything to improve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, tokens are not necessarily stored. Some compilers do store the tokens in a table or other data structure, but for a simple compiler (if there is such a thing) it's sufficient in most cases that the lexer can return the type of the next token to be parsed and then in some cases the parser might ask the lexer for the actual text that the token is made up of.

If we use your sample code,

```
if (fooBar > 5) {
  for (var i = 0; i < alot.length; i++) {
    fooBar += 2 + i;
  }
}
```

The type of the first token in this sample might be defined as TOK_IF corresponding to the "if" keyword. The next token might be TOK_LPAREN, then TOK_IDENT, then TOK_GREATER, then TOK_INT_LITERAL, and so on. What exactly the types should be is defined by you as the author of the lexer (or tokenizer) code. (Note that there are about a million different tools to help you avoid the somewhat tedious task of coming up with these details by hand.)

Except for TOK_IDENT and TOK_INT_LITERAL the tokens we've seen so far are defined entirely by their type. For these two, we would need to be able to ask the lexer for the underlying text so that we can evaluate the value of the token.

So a tiny excerpt of the parser dealing with an IF statement in pseudo-code might look something like:

```
...
  switch(lexer.GetNextTokenType())
  case TOK_IF:
    {
      // "if" statement  
      if (lexer.GetNextTokenType() != TOK_LPAREN)
        throw SyntaxError('( expected');
      ParseRelationalExpression(lexer);
      if (lexer.GetNextTokenType() != TOK_RPAREN)
        throw SyntaxError(') expected');
      ...
```

and so on.

If the compiler did choose to actually store the tokens for later reference, and some compilers do e.g. to allow for more efficient backtracking, one way would be to use a structure similar to the following

```
struct {
  int TokenType;
  char* TokenStart;
  int TokenLength;
}
```

The container for these might be a linked list or std::vector (assuming C++).

Comment: Awesome answer! Great for starters like me. You deserve more than the 1 point. Id prefer to wait and giv you a bounty as well.